# Prolog trace output to search tree

Tags: debugging, prolog, binary-search-tree, trace

I'm trying to translate the trace output from prolog to a search tree, but I'm not sure if it's correct.
Any help on how to make a search tree from the trace information is appreciated.

```
Database/Input:

rara([X|L],A,M):- 
    rara(L,[Y|A],M).

rara([M|L],L,[M]).

rara(L,M):- 
    rara(L,[],M). 

Query:

rara([a,b,c,d],X).

Trace output:
Call: (8) rara([a, b, c, d], _G922) ? creep
Call: (9) rara([a, b, c, d], [], _G922) ? creep
Call: (10) rara([b, c, d], [_G1043], _G922) ? creep
Call: (11) rara([c, d], [_G1046, _G1043], _G922) ? creep
Call: (12) rara([d], [_G1049, _G1046, _G1043], _G922) ? creep
Call: (13) rara([], [_G1052, _G1049, _G1046, _G1043], _G922) ? creep
Fail: (13) rara([], [_G1052, _G1049, _G1046, _G1043], _G922) ? creep
Redo: (12) rara([d], [_G1049, _G1046, _G1043], _G922) ? creep
Fail: (12) rara([d], [_G1049, _G1046, _G1043], _G922) ? creep
Redo: (11) rara([c, d], [_G1046, _G1043], _G922) ? creep
Fail: (11) rara([c, d], [_G1046, _G1043], _G922) ? creep
Redo: (10) rara([b, c, d], [_G1043], _G922) ? creep
Fail: (10) rara([b, c, d], [_G1043], _G922) ? creep
Redo: (9) rara([a, b, c, d], [], _G922) ? creep
Fail: (9) rara([a, b, c, d], [], _G922) ? creep
Fail: (8) rara([a, b, c, d], _G922) ? creep
```

Current search tree:

```
                     rara([a,b,c,d],X).

                |                                 |
   rara([a, b, c, d], _G922)          rara([b, c, d], [_G1043], _G922)
   X = _G922                                   |        
                                rara([c, d], [_G1046, _G1043], _G922)  
                                           |
                      rara([d], [_G1049, _G1046, _G1043], _G922)
                                        |
               rara([], [_G1052, _G1049, _G1046, _G1043], _G922)
```

Comment: Normally when searching people use just Google, but in this case using [Google Images](https://images.google.com/) search is actually better. Using Google Images search with [Prolog tree](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1536&bih=754&ei=qI4JXNDaDuKGgge4o4_QDQ&q=prolog+tree&oq=prolog+tree&gs_l=img.3..0j0i8i30l4j0i24l5.1426.2800..2905...0.0..2.60.580.11......2....1..gws-wiz-img.....0.QWLTqfjmN3Q) shows many example images of what you seek.

Comment: Another was to search is to use the correct key word with regular Google search, in this case the keyword is [SLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution).

Comment: Now if you use SWI-Prolog and know [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) there is a package [sldnfdraw](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=sldnfdraw) that genreates the LaTeX markup, but you still need to get the converted to a graphics output. I am not sure it still works.

Comment: If you want to do it by hand with images, the I find [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/) with `dot` to be very useful. It takes time to learn this, but I use it every few months.

Comment: I tried your example query and it is failing. Also when using `consult/1` to load your predicates it returned. `Warning: rara.pl:3:
        Singleton variables: [X,Y]` for the first predicate. Is this a bug?

Comment: I am hesitant to do an actual answer because 1). You have a possible bug, 2). You have not either accepted an answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52633385/1243762) or given feedback as to why you have not accepted an answer.